# Mock NgbModal in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ng-bootstrap, ng-modal

I need to mock a NgbModal to do some unit tests in angular, but I have no idea how to do this. This is my function:

```
    openModal(deviceID: string, productID: string){
        const modalRef =  this.modalService.open(ProductModal)
        modalRef.componentInstance.content = {
            deviceId: deviceID,
            productId: productID
        } 
        modalRef.componentInstance.toEmit.subscribe(($e) => {
            if ($e === true) this.reloadList();
        });
    }
```

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `modalService` is `NgbModal`, it seems the logic you want to test is inside the modal content (`ProductModal`), not `NgbModal` itself.

As you can see, after using `.open()` your `modalRef.componentInstance` will be an instance of `ProductModal`; so you can test `ProductModal` as any *component*  with e.g. component fixtures and skipping the `modalService` altogether:

(Again, assuming `ProductModal` *is* a component with proper decorations.)

```
let component: ProductModal;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductModal>;
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [ NgbModal, NgbActiveModal ],
        declarations: [ ProductModal ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductModal);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

// now you have the component in `component`, so you can test
// component.content
// component.toEmit
// …
```